# Does second-order arithmetic (Z2) prove soundness and uniform reflection for first-order arithmetic (PA)?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness, higher-order-logic

(1)  Does full second-order arithmetic (Z2) prove soundness and uniform reflection schemas for first-order arithmetic (PA)?  That is, do we have for all formulas $\phi$:
$$ \underset \phi \forall \; Z2 \vdash \square_{PA} \ulcorner \phi \urcorner \rightarrow \phi $$
and
$$ \underset \phi \forall \; Z2 \vdash \forall x: \big ( \square_{PA} \ulcorner \phi(x) \urcorner \rightarrow \phi(x) \big ) $$

?

(2)  What would be a good reference to cite to this effect?

Comment: When you say "All formulas $\phi$", do you mean formulas of PA, or formulas of second-order arithmetic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; if $\phi(x)$ is a formula of first-order arithmetic, then $Z_2$ proves
$$
(\forall x)[ \Box_{PA}\ulcorner \phi(x)\urcorner \Rightarrow \phi(x) ]
$$
(The rest of this answer would go through with $Z_2$ replaced by the subsystem with only $\Pi^1_1$ comprehension, and likely in even weaker subsystems, although that goes beyond the question.)

The argument is sketched as follows:

- $Z_2$ can construct a truth function $T_1$ for all sentences of first-order arithmetic with parameters in $\mathbb{N}$.
- $Z_2$ can prove that each axiom of PA is true under this truth function.
- $Z_2$ can prove that the set of true sentences is closed under the inference rules of PA. In other words $Z_2$ can formalize and prove $\mathbb{N} \vDash \text{PA}$.
- So $Z_2$ proves, for each $\phi(x)$ in the language of PA, that
  $$(\forall x)[\Box_{PA}\ulcorner \phi(x)\urcorner \Rightarrow T_1(\ulcorner \phi(x)\urcorner) = 1]$$
  (In fact $Z_2$ proves this with a quantifier over codes for PA-formulas $\phi$, but this isn't needed for the argument at hand.)
- For each particular formula $\phi$ of PA, $Z_2$ proves 
  $$(\forall x)[ T_1(\ulcorner \phi(x)\urcorner) = 1
  \Rightarrow \phi(x)].$$
  The proof is by induction on the structure of $\phi$ using the truth definition that was used to define $T_1$.
- The rest of the proof is immediate.

As for a reference, this is nothing deep, it is just an exercise.  I don't know whether it is mentioned anywhere in the literature, but the techniques are all standard.

Comment: Thanks, Carl!  I don't suppose you'd happen to have a reference for $Z_2$ being able to construct a truth function between PA-sentences and $\mathbb N$?  If not, it's good enough for me to know that Z2 does in fact prove uniform reflection over PA.  Thank you for the $\Pi^1_1$ reference, that gets me a bit closer to knowing the minimal second-order subsystem that will do it, which isn't a critical fact in context but is one that I was curious about.

Comment: The truth set for sentences of first-order PA is definable by a $\Pi^1_1$ formula, by just writing out all the Tarski conditions. Actually the truth set is a $\Delta^1_1$ set.  So you just write down the correct formula and apply comprehension to get the truth function - there is nothing deep to it.